# JS: Change OnClick Event from variable

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

I am trying to changing the onclick event of an button.
Here is my code:

```
var onclickEvent = 'window.open("https://www.google.com", "", "widht:20px height:30px")'
btn.onclick = function() {onclickEvent}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign like that:

```
var onclickEvent = function() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com", "", "widht:20px height:30px");
};
btn.onclick = onclickEvent;
```

With the string you have, your only option is to `eval` which is considered bad practice and not recommended:

```
var onclickEvent = 'window.open("https://www.google.com", "", "widht:20px height:30px")';
btn.onclick = function() { eval(onclickEvent); };
```

In this case you should consider what's really dynamic in this expression and use a variable for it instead of *evaling* entire javascript strings. For example if that's the url then you could have something like that:

```
var onclickEvent = function(url) {
    window.open(url, "", "widht:20px height:30px");
};

var url = 'https://www.google.com';
btn.onclick = function() { onclickEvent(url); };
```

Comment: but i want to use onclickEvent as an string so i can change the function. onclickEvent is an string from an textbox.

Comment: That's very bad practice because you will need to use `eval` as shown in my answer to execute this code. I would recommend you rethinking your design.

Comment: Why does it need to be a string? What do you need to change in the string? Can't you pass an argument to the function that updates the string?